How to map array of object to object key-value pairs in JQ?
Using JQ how do I convert array of objects to key-value pair object?
Given the JSON:
[
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "id": "123"
  },
  {
    "name": "bar",
    "id": "456"
  }
]

Desired output:
{
  "foo": "123",
  "bar": "456"
}


You can convert to an array of objects with key and value keys, then use from_entries:
map({key: .name, value: .id}) | from_entries


How do I get output to be:
`
{
"foo: 123",
"bar: 456"
}
'

@user1822391 There's a flag for compact output, --compact-output (or -c), but it'll remove all whitespace.

@user1822391 Or maybe I misunderstood your question. The JSON in your comment isn't valid.

Sorry I meant how do I get the output to format as name: id, as in { "foo": "123", "bar": "456" }

@user1822391 That's what the command does, no? See this playground.

Sorry again... I meant output as array: `[ "foo:123", "bar:456" ]

@user1822391 map(.name + ":" + .id) would do that.
